# sass-loader / bootstrap: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, sass-loader

After upgrading my Angular application from version 12 to version 17, I encountered the following error related to Sass imports when trying to build the project:

`./src/app/shared/styles/frameworks/bootstrap.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
1 │ @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
node_modules@tes\css-framework\sass\libs\bootstrap_style.scss 1:9  @import
@tes\css-framework\bootstrap.scss 5:9                                @import
src\app\shared\styles\frameworks\bootstrap.scss 1:9                  root stylesheet

./src/app/shared/styles/frameworks/bootstrap.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
1 │ @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
`

This problem only occurs after upgrading Angular to version 17. How can I resolve this Sass import error and successfully build my Angular project with Bootstrap after the upgrade?

Thanks in advance for your help!

A tryed:

```
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": ["node_modules"]
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should be able to use `@import '~node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';`. Tilde imports are being deprecated in the future, but as of today there's still no alternative